Issue Deploying Private V2Ray Subscription Link on Cloudflare Worker
I’m currently facing an issue while deploying a private V2Ray subscription link on a Cloudflare Worker. I’ve followed the steps outlined in the vfarid/v2ray-worker-sub repository, but I’m encountering an unexpected error.
Here are the steps I’ve taken:
Forked the repository from v2ray-worker
Set secrets with my Cloudflare KV settings ID.
Edited the README.md file to replace the button URL with my own GitHub repo URL.
Deployed the worker using Cloudflare Workers.
However, when I try to run the workflow, I receive an error message: “The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/deploy.yml (Line: 31, Col: 7): Unexpected value ‘with’.”
I’ve double-checked my indentation and syntax, but I’m still stuck. Could someone please guide me on how to resolve this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance for your help.
To see Error Message
